# JavaScript Code to make external site pop-up

Tags: javascript, ajax, client

i need a javascript code that would enable me, on a certain button click to let a panel open which contains another page not under my domain for example, www.google.com!

**Press Here** and upon pressing it, a popup will appear or a panel will become visible that contains Google.com in it!

thanks!

Comment: Have you done anything regarding this..?

Answer (score 3):

In a function that you [bind](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html) to the click event for the element you want to click on: [Create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement) an [iframe](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.5) and [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute) its [src](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-src), then [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild) it to an element already in the document.

Answer (score 3):

I'd look into using jquery http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

It's hosted on a CDN so it's easy to include in a document and many browsers will already have it cached decreasing the pages load time.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

jquery is a lightweight javascript library that makes selecting and manipulating page elements REALLY easy.

```
$("#button").click(function () { 
  $("#hiddenDiv").slideDown(); 
});
```

The hidden div should contain an iframe to display the off-domain page.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

Oh and if you need to dynamically assign the iframe then look into the jquery append function http://api.jquery.com/append/

```
$('#hiddenDiv').append('<iframe src="http://www.google.co.uk"></iframe>');
```

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/Rqfhc/) should put you on the right tracks.

Comment: Why has this been voted down? It seems to do exactly what the OP requires?

Comment: I voted it up to redress the balance (and because it works!) :D

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#show_frameDiv').click(function(){
        $('#frameDiv').show();
    });
    });
</script>
<style>
    #frameDiv { display: none; }
    #frameDiv iframe { width: 100%; height: 600px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="show_frameDiv">Show external site</a>

    <div id="frameDiv">
        <iframe src="http://www.bbc.co.uk">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
        </iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

This will work only if the site you are trying to display allows frames. Otherwise you may need to open the site in a separate browser window.

Answer (score -3):

use window.Open method like this:

window.open ("www.google.com","mywindow");

see 
http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

for more details.